# How do I output from a RPi3 to Hisense 4k screen?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I've tried the suggestions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=79330) and when I first turn the Pi on, as it's booting the screen says it's running at 4k @ 15hz as expected. When the desktop would normally appear though, the screen goes blank.

I've checked by edid settings (see below) but am none-the-wiser as to what I need to adjust to get this running or whether it's simply not possible to drive this screen at 15hz?

```
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing edit.dat...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 115x65 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend !active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is HISENSE
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 50-75 Hz, horizontal is 15-69 kHz, max pixel clock is 300 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 3840x2160p hfp:176 hs:88 hbp:296 vfp:8 vs:10 vbp:72 pixel clock:297 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 30 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 3840x2160p @30 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 3840x2160p hfp:176 hs:88 hbp:296 vfp:8 vs:10 vbp:72 pixel clock:297 MHz
HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz (16)
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are 21 08 00
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 4, 640x480p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 9, 800x600p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 16, 1024x768p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x81C0 8140 8180 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 85, 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (16:9) in standard timing 0
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 32, 1280x960p @ 60 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 1
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 35, 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (5:4) in standard timing 2
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:no, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:1
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1360x768p @ 60 Hz (39)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz (5)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (4)
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 95
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 94
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 93
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 2, 720x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 5, 1920x1080i @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 16, 1920x1080p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 17, 720x576p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 19, 1280x720p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 20, 1920x1080i @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 31, 1920x1080p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 32, 1920x1080p @ 24Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 33, 1920x1080p @ 25Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 34, 1920x1080p @ 30Hz 
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
HDMI:EDID found audio format 6 channels AC3, sample rate: 32|44|48 kHz, bitrate: 640 kbps
HDMI:EDID found audio format 8 channels Dobly Digital+, sample rate: 32|44|48 kHz, codec define: 0
HDMI:EDID found Video Capability DB length 2
HDMI:EDID video capability: CE:1 IT:2 PT:3 QS:3
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 13
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 1.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB supports AI:no, dual link DVI:no
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB deep colour support - 48-bit:no 36-bit:yes 30-bit:yes DC_yuv444:yes
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB max TMDS clock 300 MHz
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB does not support content type
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB supports extended resolutions 1,2,3
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (3) 720x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (18) 720x576p @ 50Hz
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 61864)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 66472)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (4) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 3635592)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 4273832)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (9) 800x600p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 40 MHz has a score of 28800
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz (score 5398248)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (16) 1024x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 65 MHz has a score of 47185
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (19) 1280x720p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 117160
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (20) 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 128680
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (31) 1920x1080p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 232360
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (32) 1920x1080p @ 24 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 124532
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (32) 1280x960p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 98728
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (33) 1920x1080p @ 25 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 128680
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (34) 1920x1080p @ 30 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 149416
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (35) 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 103643
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (39) 1360x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 85 MHz has a score of 4562668
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (85) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 80296
HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
edid_parser exited with code 0
```